# contrapositive of $a^2 + b^2$ is divisible by $8$ iff $a$ and $b$ are both even

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm working on creating a contrapositive statement to the one above and this is what I've come up with:

$a^2 + b^2$ is not divisible by $8$ iff $a$ or $b$ are not even.

I know that typically a contrapositive setup follows something like
If $A$ then $B$
Contrapositive: Not $B$ then not $A$

I'm just not sure if I have the contrapositive statement right or it should be saying $a^2 + b^2$ is not divisible by $8$ iff $a$ and $b$ are not even.

Comment: **Hint:** $m$ divides $n$ iff $n=qm$ for some $q\in\Bbb Z$; in particular, $c$ is even iff $c=2d$ for some $d\in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: You can simplfy saying $a^2+b^2$ is not divisible by $8$ iff at least one of $a$, $b$ is odd.

Comment: @Bernard I thought that it implied at least one of but I wasn't sure.  Thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186105/sum-of-square-of-integers-when-divided-by-8-cant-leave-a-remainder-of-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposition is false.
$2^2 + 4^2 = 20$ is not divisible by 8.

The contrapositive to "P implies Q" is "not Q implies not P".
The notion of a contrapositive of an equivalence is bizarre.
It is simply negating both sides.

Thus, 
8 does not divide $a^2 + b^2$ iff a or b is odd.
That of course, is false by the above counterexample.

Is there an odd a and an integer b for which 8 divides $a^2 + b^2$?

Comment: I can't tell, you may have meant bizarre. I don't know what baraaz means.