# a) For $a \in \Bbb Z$ find all the possible remainders of $a^2$ divided by $8$; b) Prove that there are no integer solutions for $x^2+y^2+z^2+1=8w$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> a) For $a \in \Bbb Z$ find all the possible remainders of $a^2$ divided by $8$
>
> b) Prove that there are no integer solutions for $x^2+y^2+z^2+1=8w$

---

For the first part:

I checked two cases, if $a$ is even and if $a$ is odd

if $a$ is even the $a^2=4k^2$ and then $8q=4k^2$ so the remainder is $0$

if $a$ is odd then $a^2=(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1$ so $4k(k+1)+1=8q$ and the remainder is $1$

for the second part

I wanted to check all possible values of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ for $mod8$ first I got that the only possible values are $0,1,4$ for each squared term because $0^2 \equiv0 (mod8),1^2,3^2,5^2,7^2 \equiv1 (mod8)$ and $2^2,6^2 \equiv4 (mod8)$ so all the possible values for $x^2+y^2+z^2$ will be depending on how many are odd or even

if all of them are even then the possible values are $0,4$

if all of them are odd then the possible value is $3$

if 2 are even and 1 is odd the values are $1,5$

and lastly if 2 are odd and 1 is even then the values are $6,2$

so I got the values $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ adding $1$ to the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$

so I got everything except $0$ which means it leaves a remainder but does that mean that there is no integer solution to the equation? I am not sure if what I did is right or is there another way

Thanks for any tips and help

Comment: What is your question?  For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically OK, with a few small caveats.

1. You seem not to realize that subproblem a) is a preparartion for b). In a) you wrote that

> if $a$ is even ... the remainder is $0$

which is incorrect, but as you later solved subproblem b), you got the correct result that the square of an even number leaves remainer $0$ **or $4$** when divided by 8.

2. You got the correct result that $x^2+y^2+z^2+1$ leaves, when divided by $8$, a remainder in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, which does not contain $0$. And of course that means that $x^2+y^2+z^2+1 = 8w$ has no integer solutions, because the right side is always divisible by $8$, while the left side is **never** divisible by $8$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs & PSQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Comment: @BillDubuque I try to help people with their problems. I do not agree that is is **best** to delete answers that do so. The OP had a problem, solved it, had questions about it, which I tried to address.

Comment: Creating thousands of duplicate answers to common exercises is a very poor way to help people because it makes it very difficult (to impossible) for students to *search* for good answers (which means that all the prior work that community has done has gone to waste).

Comment: 1. OP has solved the problem given to them themselves. They weren't sure about something, so posted it. I clarified. Searching for other answers  might be helpful, agreed.
2. You cannot search for **good** answers, you can only search for questions. The canonical answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779784/show-that-an-integer-of-the-form-8k-7-cannot-be-written-as-the-sum-of-three is certainly good, and may have helped, agreed. But OP had problems recongising the last step of his solution as "enough", which isn't addressed in those answer.

Comment: 3. How is adding an answer to a problem making it "difficult (to impossible) for students to search for good answers". It's a new answer, they might find it!

Comment: @Ingix Thank you for the help and great explanation! 
Bill I did not ask for someone to work as a "proof checking machine" I showed my ways, what I thought about when solving and what I don't understand (mentioned in the last lines)
I understand the sites rules and I follow them, not in a bad way but I don't see the point of your comment especially after Ingix gave an answer which obviously helped me a lot and hopefully will help other people if they encounter it.
Thanks for the help again.

Comment: @Adamrk You did not follow the rules for a solution-verification question. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

for the second part, You're basically solving x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 7 (-1) mod 8. The solution by Ingix is a nice one. Mine here tells you that 7 cannot be written as a sum of 3 squares since it's congruent to 3 mod 4. You'll see that in the Pythagorean triple's section.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs & PSQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)